# Messenger bot with additional app permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-permissions

I develop a chatbot for Messenger, which uses additional app permission - `user_friends`. I have a users leaderboard webview in my bot. User can log in with Facebook in this webview to see his friends and their scores.

In my app settings I choose a Web platform where as a site, I entered a link to the bot. Also I linked app and my page in Business Manager.

I passed a `pages_messaging` review. But I can't pass the app review. Reviver sends me a message:

> The Facebook Login button is not currently working properly in your app. When clicked, the button should immediately lead a user to log in with Facebook, and the user should be able to successfully sign into their Facebook account.
>   Please make sure your Facebook Login button is working correctly and accessible outside your company, then resubmit your app for review.
>   Notes From Your Reviewer:
>   I've attached some screenshots that may help you understand my response better. You can find them here: https://scontent.fhen2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8008-6/39074871_995233137350165_8046464733332635648_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=46cc08fd4cc4511a5a76476112048bc0&oe=5C04B1F2

I don't understand how reviver got this error. 
Maybe I don't understand how to correctly connect my bot and app? 
Maybe I should create test users and test page that reviewer can log in, because test users can't interact with real pages?

People who use Facebook app permissions in their Messenger bots can you help me?

Comment: _“I entered a link to the bot”_ - and that means what exactly? Does that link/URL return an actual HTML document where users will find your login button?

Comment: Link - https://m.me/<page_name>. When user starts conversation with bot he get a message with link to Facebook login. I can't use regular Account linking button because it is not allow to get app permissions for user. Also I show a link to Facebook login in my leaderboard webview.

Comment: _“I can't use regular Account linking button because it is not allow to get app permissions for user.”_ - no clue what you mean by that. I am not aware of any such restrictions, that said you could not use it to perform a “normal” Graph API Login and ask for certain permissions.

Comment: Ok, I mistaken in this. But this does not explain, how reviwer got a page like on screenshot with this strange url - https://www.messenger.com/login/nonce/

Comment: Perhaps due to the fact that you just put your messenger link into the Website platform settings field … that should contain a link to an actual website _you_ provide.

Comment: But I don't have site exactly. I have a chatbot with webviews where I use app permissions and I can't provide link to my leaderboard page where reviwer can find login button, because user should start conversation with bot first.

Comment: Well that content inside those webviews doesn’t fall from the sky, you must have that hosted somewhere? But I am not sure if you _can_ get this through review; they expect to see an actual “running app” under each platform you submit for review - so if you configure the “Website” platform, then that is supposed to be usable on its own. If that’s not how your app is supposed to work, then you can only try and explain that in very detailed manner in your review instructions, and hope they can follow.

Comment: You right. Thank you for you help. I just put Facebook login button in my leaderbord webview and made this page available to users who did not start a conversation with the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer copied over from comments].

> I have a chatbot with webviews where I use app permissions and I can't provide link to my leaderboard page where reviwer can find login button, because user should start conversation with bot first.

[cbroe] That content inside those webviews doesn’t fall from the sky, you must have that hosted somewhere. So this should be the address you enter for the “Website” platform, if you want to implement general Facebook login there.

But I am not sure if you can get this through review; they expect to see an actual “running app” under each platform you submit for review - so if you configure the “Website” platform, then that is supposed to be usable on its own. If that’s not how your app is supposed to work, then you can only try and explain that in very detailed manner in your review instructions, and hope they can follow.